# Why does read -r eat text?

Tags: shell-script, shell, dash

I have a `names.txt` file with with the top line of text being

```
51 Pipe-line\Closed3\00001011_-_Portfolio\UW\Old\NID50_Future_022814.xlsx
```

I would like to write new filenames replacing `\` with `/`

I wrote a `script.sh` and invoked it using `sh script.sh`.
My first attempt...

---

```
while read one two three; do

  new=$(echo $two|tr '\\' '/')
  echo $one
  echo $two
  echo $three
  echo $new

done < ./names.txt
```

---

```
51
Pipe-lineClosed300001011_-_PortfolioUWOldNID50_Future_022814.xlsx

Pipe-lineClosed300001011_-_PortfolioUWOldNID50_Future_022814.xlsx
```

---

This ate the `/` char. I found out passing a `-r` will show the `/` so my next attempt was

```
 while read -r one two three; do

  new=$(echo $two|tr '\\' '/')
  echo $one
  echo $two
  echo $three
  echo $new

done < ./names.txt
```

---

```
51
Pipe-line\Closed3

Pipe-line/Closed3
```

---

This eats half the filename. What is happening? How do I get this to work?

Comment: See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: Why on earth do you want to convert backslashes to slashes?  This sounds like a very wrong-headed attempt somewhere way down the line of the XY problem.  Are you perhaps moving files from Windows to Linux?

Comment: s3 to s3. `/` is handled much better there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the `read`, but the `echo`.

> I wrote a `script.sh` and invoked it using `sh script.sh`.

In Debian and Ubuntu, `sh` is `dash`, in which `echo` evaluates C-style backslash-escapes in its arguments:

```
$ dash -c 'foo="foo\000bar"; echo "$foo"; printf "%s\n" "$foo"' 
foo
foo\000bar
```

The `\000` gets turned to the NUL byte, which apparently ends the string that `echo` outputs. Quoting the variable doesn't help here, since it only changes the processing of the shell command line before the command itself runs, and here it's the `echo` itself that handles the backslashes.

This is a known portability issue, described in more detail here: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

For example, Bash's `echo` does the backslash-processing if given the `-e` argument.

The question was originally tagged with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), so if you want to run the script using Bash, run it with `bash script.sh`, not `sh script.sh`.

Comment: Ah.. I updated the tags. Works now, appreciate the explanation too.

Comment: @lonewarrior556, when you do that `new=$(echo $two | tr)`, the string gets cut on the `\000`, and `$new` never contains the rest. The other backslashes are followed by capital letters, and aren't valid escapes, so the echo just leaves them alone.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished in a much simpler and robust way with sed:

```
sed -i 's|\\|/|g' myfile
```

Gives:

cat myfile
    51 Pipe-line/Closed3/00001011_-_Portfolio/UW/Old/NID50_Future_022814.xls

**EDIT**:

Following your comment, this is the way I would achieve this:

```
for i in $(cat test | awk '{print $2}')
do
  mv $i `sed 's|\\|/|g' <<< $i`
done
```

Comment: I will need to run a mv command at some point using the old filename and new file name. I still need to read the old file names from file

Comment: `-i` is the "in place" flag, meaning it edits the source file. If you remove it the changed string is printed to STDOUT. Then you can just redirect it to a file. I will edit the answer.

Comment: In my example I only copied one line in a file, since I don't know what the file really contains

Comment: `script.sh: 1: renametest.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: @Fox That's right, it is a typo (I copied the ooutput of sed -i and made a mistake)

Answer (score 0):

Just this will suffice:

```
tr '\\' / < names.txt
```